# Training RBF Network

Tags: neural-network

Could someone please provide some information about the training of a RBF Network?

My researches showed that there are several ways to train such a network, but some seem more like heuristics than knowledge based approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RBF network has 3 layers, input layer, 1 hidden layer and output layer which is just a single neuron in case of binary classification or regression.
you can train RBF completely supervised, which is not a trivial task without a framework but not that hard, or use an unsupervised approach which is simpler for calculating the parameters of RBF network, but you should still compute the output layer weights in a supervised manner with gradient descent.all weights for the input layer are 1 as far as I know.

you have 3 parameters to find, **centers** , **spread**, and **Weights** for last layer. most common  choice of basis function is Gaussian.
use k-means on data set to find centers. it is your choice how many centers but from what I've learnt from theory in university, it should be half the number of your samples for start, then you can add or reduce the number base on results you get from test set.
get the mean of distances between every two closest centers, that is one way to compute the spread(width) of each center.
use gradient descent for learning the weights of last layer.

one thing to remember is that machine learning is awesome because we find solutions for ill-posed problems, of course some approaches seems more like heuristics but they are best solutions we know for now.you need to tune parameters of a model and make it work. :)

Answer (score 1):

[Radial basis function network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_network#Training)

just visit this Wikipedia page, and get details.

Comment: Thanks! I know this approach but it's not what I was actually looking for. I need some more detailed approaches from someone experienced with RBF Networks. So well, is it necessary to do a gradient descent for a proper setting of the variance (sigma) or is there a better approach?